# Casting an object to an Array using Array.from

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create an `ArrayBuffer` from a WebSocket's stringified data.

The stringified data is a `Float32Array`.

Here's what I attempted:

```
var parsed = JSON.parse(streamData);
var arrayed = Array.from(parsed);
var arr32 = Float32Array.from(arrayed);
var kbuff = new ArrayBuffer(arr32);
```

The variable `parsed` looks like this:

[image]

But then my `Array.from` results in an empty array:

[image]

What am I missing here?
And - Is this the proper way of creating my `ArrayBuffer`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Array.from()` requires the object to have a length property. Use `Object.values()` instead:

```js
const parsed = {
  0: 'a',
  1: 'b',
  2: 'c',
}

const arrayed1 = Array.from(parsed);
const arrayed2 = Object.values(parsed);

console.log({ arrayed1 });
console.log({ arrayed2 });
```

Comment: Thanks Ori this works now, I will set as a correct answer, meanwhile, can you assist why `var kbuff = new ArrayBuffer(arr32)` creates an empty `ArrayBuffer` ?

Comment: `ArrayBuffer`'s constructor expects  a number (`length`), and not an array - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer/ArrayBuffer

Comment: Thanks, Happy Rosh Hashana. I passed the `.buffer` and it works.

Answer (score 0):

For Array.from need to iterable argument with property length.
Try to use Object.values(parsed) for getting array from your parsed values and then use Float32Array, seems it's can help you.
Or you can get array from pais [key, value] use Objest.entries(parsed)